# How can I make a digital audio panning controlled by a microcontroller?

Tags: audio, resistance, potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

I've been trying to pan an audio signal between 2 speakers, in a way that I could program it to create an autopan effect.

It seems an easy thing to do, but I have been struggling a lot with it and some help would be appreciated. Here is what I've tried to do:

1: Using Arduino with digital pot:

I tried to use the MCP4141 (100K) digital pot with an Arduino through SPI communication. It did work, but the resistance is not enough as in its highest resistance the sound is still audible. I even tried to use 2 pots in parallel to double the resistance, still, 200K was not enough and I realised I needed a much higher value. I tried to use a 1000K pot, the AD5241BRZ1M, which is the only one that seems to be available at 1000K (1M) resistance. However, not much information is available about it and I could not make it work with an Arduino. After many tries I had to give up.

Now I'm considering using a Teensy, but it seems to expensive for my project (teensy + audio board) and I don't know if it would work.

Is there any other solution?? Are there other types of potentiometers I'm missing?

Thanks.

Below is my attempt of using it with MCP4141 (with only 1 pot and 1 speaker, as if I make this work I can add the other later).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fveG77.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

MCP4141 datasheet:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22059a.pdf

Comment: Resistance value of your pot is not relevant. What is relevant is how much signal the pot lets pass when set to zero. Please show your schematics.

Comment: A potentiometer is not just a variable resistance as you imply. It's a ratio of two resistances : as you increase one to 100K you also decrease the other to practically 0 giving practically infinite attenuation. So check your circuit topology - better, post your schematic here and link to the MCP4141 datasheet.

Comment: I have just added the schematics...

Comment: Something to bear in mind is that the MCP4141 part you are using does not support voltages lower than Vss (aka Ground). To work correctly you are going to need to shift your voltages to Vcc/2. Typically this means AC coupling the inputs with a DC blocking capacitor and then biasing to half the supply voltage with a voltage divider made with two identical resistors. In addition DC blocking capacitors will be required on the outputs.

Comment: @PeterCamilleri .. Ok! Thanks for this information.

Comment: Do it analog! Some J-FETs will do the thing.

Comment: Hi @JakubRakus, thanks for your suggestion. I thought about using a transistor before, but would this be OK for audio signals? If you can draw a schematics as an answer that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @ArtLyra If transistors weren't good for audio signals, we would probably still use tubes. The keyword is: "voltage controlled resistor", for example: www.vishay.com/docs/70598/70598.pdf

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make a digital audio panning controlled by a
>   microcontroller?

Try using this circuit: -

[image]

But scale up the resistors to suit your pot. The down side of using a digital pot is the wiper resistance. For the MCP4141 (100K) you used, it has a wiper resistance of up to 300 ohms, so there will be a small amount of leak through on the "muted" channel. I estimate it will be about 0.3/164 kohm if the 8k2 is scaled up to 162 kohm. In log terms that's about -55 dB. Is this enough? Only you can say.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the schematics is not completely clear to me....I'm not sure how to connect the MCP4141 with the 8K2 resistors..

Comment: The MCP4141 has three pot connections - they replace the three connections and the pot above. A and B are outputs to your two power amps that feed the two speakers you mention in your question.

Comment: I see... So in this case the pot is used to balance the signal between the 2 speakers..but this will generate a linear balance, isn't it?
What I was looking for was actually a way of controlling 2 dig pots, so I could adjust the panning law by programming the microcontroller. For instance, pot #1 would go up on speaker 1, while pot 2 go down on speaker 2...then I could adjust the function when it goes up and down.
I will try your method later anyway, thanks.

Comment: No, it's not a balance control. It's a panning control. You asked for a panning control. Panning is where you take one signal and move it left or right. If you want a stereo balance then this is not what you asked in your question.

Comment: Yes, I understand panning perfectly, I've done it many times through Pure Data and other software... My purpose is panning. Sorry if I wasn't very clear. I was thinking I needed two pots for this, but it seems I was wrong. If I use just one as you suggested, I may be able to change the function and make it non-linear as well... I just realised that.

Comment: Try and explain the non-linear bit in more detail. I wouldn't call panning using a linear pot as a linear process.

Comment: Ok..I want to program something to move a sound between R and L speakers, right? If it's linear, the numbers go from 0. to 1. (or in the digital pot from 0 to the max step number) in 1 speaker, while in the other it goes from 1. to 0, the opposite. This is a linear effect, the sound appears to be distant when in the centre.
But I'm hoping that I can program the digital pot to do the 0. to 1. in a non-linear scale. I've done this before, so the programming/math bit is fine for me.

Comment: I tried to use the circuit you suggested, but unfortunately it didn't work. Probably I didn't do it right. The Vin is supposed to be the audio in, connecting to the wiper, right? If you could draw a full schematics that would be brilliant. Otherwise, thanks anyway.

Comment: Vin doesn't connect to the wiper. The wiper connects to ground. That is the full circuit as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: OK, so according to you:
A: audio output to spk1
B: audio output to spk2
Wiper: ground
Where do I put the audio to go inside the MCP?

Comment: The 5 k potentiometer shown in the diagram is the potentiometer position. Vin is Vin. If you are using a 10 k digipot then scale all the resistors up by 2. If using a 100 k pot then scale the resistors up by 20.

Comment: Ok, so Vin is normal voltage power...5V in this case. But how about the audio signal line? There is just the outputs. Sorry but it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Vin is the audio input. Not shown (because you have already done this according to what you say in your question) are the digital connections to the digipot. Make sure that the audio inputted to the device is biased around half Vcc to ensure that clipping or chip damage doesn't occur. If you don't understand that google the phrase I used.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. So I did correctly, audio sig > 8k2 > A (mcp) > 39k > spk1..and I programmed the MCP to go up and down, but through this method nothing changed, the signal was stable. Anyway, I will try again.  And I will check how to do the vcc/2. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you have damaged the device by not putting a safe and correctly biased audio signal into it in your previous testing.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say the audio is already in digital form, do the gain adjustments digitally.  For each incoming sample, multiply it by (1-PAN) to the first speaker and PAN to the second.  PAN is a variable that goes from 0 to 1 to control how much the sound is panned from the first speaker to the second.

### Added

I was trying to show the conceptually simple way to do this.  However, as Colin_s pointed out in a comment, linearly blending the voltage won't give you perceived constant amplitude during the pan.  You need to keep the sum of the squares of the voltages constant, not the sum of the voltages as in the example above.

Again though, you already have a digital processor, so this is very easy to do.  You can either compute the correct fraction into each speaker on the fly, or use a pre-computed lookup table.

Note that doing a constant-power pan is something the analog solutions don't do well, at least not easily.  This is better and more easily done digitally.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I know how to do it digitally, I've done many times using Pure Data and a Raspberry PI.. The problem is how to use this with a microcontroller. I appreciate your answer anyway.

Comment: You could use a better microcontroller, the parts used for arduinos are painfully slow in comparison to any half decent modern part.

Comment: @Olin The problem with using that method for panning is that in the with the signal in the centre you get half the power as you do when panned hard left or right. (p = i^2 * R, ignore R assuming it's constant) Panned hard left `left = sample, right = 0, power = left^2 + right^2 = sample ^ 2` whereas centre panned `left = 0.5 * sample, right = 0.5 * sample, power = 0.25 * sample ^2 + 0.25 * sample^2 = 0.5*sample^2`.  
The solution is to use `left = sample*sqrt(1.0-panning);
right= sample*sqrt(panning);`

Comment: Yes, I know this... I will get a linear panning. The square root is only one possibility between other panning laws.
But before adding the maths to the program, I need to start linearly. Thanks.

Comment: Andrew, what other microcontroller do you suggest then?

Comment: Some sort of arm M3 or M4 would be more suitable if you want to do the maths in the CPU. That would give you a 100-120 MHz 32 bit CPU rather than the 16 MHz 8 bit part you are using.

Comment: Thank you..I've never used these ARM, but I will have a look and see if I can learn how to program them as they seem very useful.

Comment: @ArtLyra there is an ARM "arduino" called the Due. check that out.

Comment: @Colin: See addition to the answer.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Looks good to me, have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the digital potentiometer, consider using an analog VCA (voltage controlled amplifier). You can drive the voltage control input with an analog output from your micro.

You can find integrated VCAs designed for the audio industry which have an inherently log control law - this will address difficulties and limitations associated with linear R-DACs. Check out THAT corporation.

This approach will have some associated analog design challenges, but will offload the amount of work to do in the digital domain!

Comment: I will try this as well. I've never used a VCA. It's good to know there's an alternative! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears from your drawing that you are using the potentiometer as a simple series resistor.  For a full-range volume control, you need to use the pot as a voltage divider, like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwZnkI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This has worked, although it added a lot of noise, which I think it's because of the VSS. As @PeterCamilleri commented on my question: "to work correctly you are going to need to shift your voltages to Vcc/2."
This is a little bit inconvenient as I don't know exactly how to do it and my electronics knowledge is very short.. So maybe I will try with another digital pot that doesn't require this, as now I know the resistance is not so important. Thanks.